# JPA 2.0 predicate condition lists in query builder

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

Code:

```
List<Predicate> conditionsList = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
Predicate onStart = criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(criteriaRoot.get("insertDateTime"), startTradeDate);
Predicate onEnd = criteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(criteriaRoot.get("insertDateTime"), endTradeDate);
conditionsList.add(onStart);
conditionsList.add(onEnd);

CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = this.entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<MyClass> criteriaQuery = 
criteriaBuilder.createQuery(MyClass.class);
Root<MyClass> criteriaRoot = criteriaQuery.from(MyClass.class);
criteriaQuery.select(criteriaRoot).where(conditionsList);
```

The last line above doesn't compile because its expecting the `conditionsList` object to be a List of Boolean not list of Predicate.

Please advise me on the correct way of adding predicates above to the `hibernate` criteria?

Comment: You should add the compiler error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the `List<Predicate>` into an array `Predicate[]` like this:

```
criteriaQuery.select(criteriaRoot).where(conditionsList.toArray(new Predicate[] {}));
```